# I can't update the sqlite3 version in python 3.8 command line?

Tags: python, sqlite, redhat, read-the-docs, sqlite3-python

I am following the pip steps in the manual for the installation of readthedocs. However, in the requests of this installation, sqlite3 has specified a minimum of 3.19 and above. I am upgrading sqlite3 version 3.17 to 3.40 on redhat 7.9 linux server. When I look with "Sqlite3 --version ", I see that it has been updated to version 3.40. However, when I check with the command "import sqlite3 sqlite3.sqlite.version " on the python3.8 command line, it appears as 3.17. 3.40 does not seem to be updated. Why pyhton3 still detects 3.17 even though I updated sqlite3 on Redhat and it shows 3.40 with sqlite3 --version. How can I overcome this problem?

I updated Redhat 7.9 sqlite3 from version 3.17 to 3.40 but with no results.

Comment: maybe you upgraded on the wrong python version.  can you confirm this ?

Comment: I assum you have now installed two sqlite3 versions, one for linux and the other comes with python. Check the program path.  in python you can check the version with `import sqlite3
print("SQLite Version -sqlite",sqlite3.sqlite_version)
print("SQLite Version -pysqlite_version:",sqlite3.version)`